# How do I override the default label text in my MVC3 View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, label

I have a labelfor attricbute that is displaying the default label text in my MVC3 Razor View. But I the label to display different text. How can I accomplish this here is an example of my code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CA_AgencyID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CA_AgencyID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CA_AgencyID)
    </div>
```

Comment: -1 not clear enough what do you need.

Comment: I am trying to change the Text inside the label element. Right now it is only taking the default text. And if I put a @Html.label it displays the default label text and the new label text I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this is to add the [DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) to your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   [DisplayName("CA Agency Id")]
   public sting CA_AgencyID { get; set;}
}
```